# How to use numeric.js

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to use numeric.js properly (from http://www.numericjs.com/index.php). 
I have a main JavaScript file, main.js, and in that I would like to call the numeric function "numeric.mul". The numeric.js file is taken from http://www.numericjs.com/lib/numeric-1.2.6.js and this .js file, my main.js and my index.html file are all saved in the same folder. Inside the body tags in my html file i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Thesis </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="numeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in my main.js file I write:

```
var x, y, z;
x = [1, 2];
y = [3, 4];
z = numeric.mul(x,y);
```

When I run this it says that "numeric" is undefined. What is wrong?

Comment: `numeric.js` must be referenced before `main.js`

Comment: because you include it after you use it. It is like trying to eat  sandwich before you make it. If you open up your developer console, it would have given you an error message

Comment: @LaljiTadhani And there is zero jquery used.... why would it be needed?

Comment: Any feedback, have you try it ?

Comment: @Aria, yes you are right and I had done this before and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TereseAmmundsen Then make sure  the `src` of`numeric.js` is correct.

Comment: @Aria you mean that the numeric.js is correct? It is an online open source file, I don't think it should be necessary to edit it if it's online. But you think it's the numeric.js file that is the problem and not my implementation?

Comment: No, According to `src` of `numeric.js` it is clear that you have download the file and add it to your project solution, I mean check it for example it may exist in Script folder in your solution , then `src` would be `/scripts/numeric.js`

Comment: index.html, main.js and numeric.js are all in the same folder. It can find and execute main.js just fine, it's only numeric.js it for some reasons doesnt get. So all the files are in /Homepage/

Comment: Paste a picture of your solution to your question that we can see, or change the `src` to `http://www.numericjs.com/lib/numeric-1.2.6.js` then try..

Comment: It works now! Thank you! :) I am embarrassed to say that the file name was nuneric.js and not numeric.js....

Comment: So the source path was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call directly from the website:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The library in questions is `numeric.js` not `numeral.js`. So the CDN URL is `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

In you'r folder The library in questions is numeric-1.2.6.js not numeric.js .So simply change numeric.js to numeric-1.2.6.js

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please test what you answer, the URL OP posted is not accessible anymore, see https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/numericjs.com